# Upstream error while pulling PR from GitHub

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I am trying to checkout specific PR #30 just for testing from Dev branch on repo `some_repo`.

So far did:

`git clone some_repo.git`
(that checked out Dev branch)

Then tried:

```
git fetch upstream pull/30/head:dev
```

that gives error:

```
fatal: 'upstream' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Tried as well:

```
git fetch origin pull/30/head:dev
fatal: Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/dev of non-bare repository
```

What should I do next?

```
git remote -v                                                                                                                                                                                             
origin  some_repo.git (fetch)
origin  ome_repo.git (push)
```

Based on robertklep suggestion - was able to get:

```
git fetch origin pull/30/head:pr-30

remote: Counting objects: 18, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
remote: Total 18 (delta 10), reused 18 (delta 10), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (18/18), done.
From some_repo
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/30/head -> pr-30

git branch -a | cat
* dev
  pr-30

git checkout pr-30

git branch -a | cat
  dev
* pr-30
```

Comment: Could you post what the command `git remote -v` gives back?

Comment: Posted in a question.

Comment: Ok but you marked out the important part, is the link to the repo correct? :-) Did you add an SSH key to you remote git repository? You'll need this for remote repos such as Gitlab & Github.

Comment: I can git clone - does that mean that I should be able to git fetch PR as well? (or still need SSH keys?)

Comment: You still need SSH keys, because you can clone if it is a public directory, but pushing wouldn't work. In github, add your public ssh key found in ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to your account and that should solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the remote is "origin", not "upstream":

```
git fetch origin pull/30/head:dev
```

If `dev` is an existing branch, this won't work. Instead, you can fetch to a new branch like this:

```
git fetch origin pull/30/head:pr-30
```

(the new branch is called `pr-30`)

Comment: Tried that as well - posted in a question.

Comment: try `pull/30/head:pr-30` (which will create a new branch "pr-30") and subsequently `git checkout pr-30`